# How to add custom program header to ELF file?

Tags: gcc, ld

I need to add a custom segment to standard ELF file. Even I find some manual, I cannot do it. Could anyone give some help? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the attempts/things you have tried?

Comment: @Castaglia My project has two files `main.c` and `secure.c`. I hope put code of `main.c` to .text segment and put code of `secure.c` to my custom segment .secure.

Comment: Do you know about `__attribute__((section))`?  Otherwise, read the GNU `ld` manual about linker scripts.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry if I confuse in above description. I mean segment within program header table, not section.